Context returns null initially and screens do not re-render when context returns a session
I have three basic routes with tanstack-router. I simply want to to check if there is an active supabase session supplied by my auth context. If there is a session go to the signup-success screen, if not stay on the index screen.
I'm following the tanstack-router example here
auth.tsx
export const AuthContext = React.createContext<AuthContext | null>(null);

export function AuthProvider({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  const [session, setSession] = React.useState<Session | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    supabase.auth.getSession().then(({ data: { session } }) => {
      setSession(session);
    });
    const {
      data: { subscription },
    } = supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange((_event, session) => {
      setSession(session);
    });
    return () => subscription.unsubscribe();
  }, []);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ session }}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}

useAuth.tsx
export function useAuth() {
  const context = React.useContext(AuthContext);
  if (!context) {
    throw new Error("useAuth must be used within an AuthProvider");
  }

  return context;
}

Index.tsx
const HomeScreen = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const { i, c }: ParamProps = Route.useSearch();

  if (!i || !c) return <Navigate to='/invite-error' replace />;

  const handleSignup = async () => {
    const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.signUp({
      email,
      password,
      data: { org_id: i, invite_code: c },
    });

    if (error) {
      console.error(error);
      return;
    }

    console.log(data);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Home</h1>
      <input
        type='text'
        placeholder='Email'
        value={email}
        onChange={(event) => setEmail(event.target.value)}
      />
      <input
        type='password'
        placeholder='Password'
        value={password}
        onChange={(event) => setPassword(event.target.value)}
      />
      <button onClick={handleSignup}>Sign Up</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export const Route = createFileRoute("/")({
  beforeLoad: async ({ context }) => {
    if (context.auth.session) {
      redirect({
        to: "/signup-success",
        replace: true,
      });
    }
  },
  component: () => <HomeScreen />,
  errorComponent: () => <div>error</div>,
});

What I'm doing

Context initially is null
Check if there is a session from supabase
Set the session in state

What I'm seeing

State gets set with session on context
Context for some reason returns null even after state updated so routing fails.

I think the beforeLoads gets the initial null and then proceeds with rendering the HomeScreen component as normal which is what I expect but I don't get why it will not rerender when the context state is updated with the session and then redirect to the signup-success screen.
I have an example of it all here

So in the end I just ended up getting the session in a useEffect like I always do. Missing out on the features that tanstack router provides but needed to get going with this.

Yeah I have the same issue, the context is initially null which causes flickering when the context is populated later.
My current solution is to add a type like
export type Auth = {
  session: Session | null;
  loaded: boolean;
};

and use the loaded flag as a double-check before checking the session/auth
const [auth, setAuth] = useState<Auth>({ loaded: false, session: null });// the initial state

export interface HypeLogContext {
  auth: Auth;
}

export const router = createRouter({
  routeTree,
  context: {
    auth: {
      loaded: false,
      session: null,
    },
  },
});

  beforeLoad({ context, location }) {
    if (context.auth.loaded && !context.auth.session)
      throw redirect({
        to: "/authentication",
        search: {
          redirect: location.href,
        },
      });
  },

